# Android - println needs a messege

Tags: java, android, mysql

Android - println needs a messege

I am Having An Error Like "println needs a messege".
Please Help Me.

I Use Android Studio 2.0

Here is LOGCAT :

> "12-13 03:48:40.598 2129-2129/com.mysqlapp.bug.mysqlapp
>   W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input
>   event receiver has already been disposed."

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText etUserName,etPassword;
    String userName,password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        etUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
        etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    }
    public void btnLoginClick(View v)
    {
        try
        {
            userName = etUserName.getText().toString();
            password = etPassword.getText().toString();
            Log.d("Hello","Here");
            MySqlDatabaseHelper sqlCls = new MySqlDatabaseHelper(this);
            sqlCls.doInBackground("login",userName,password);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            alert.setTitle("Something Went Wrong");
            alert.setMessage("-"+ex.getMessage()+"-");
            alert.show();
        }

    }
}
```

Database Helper Class : MySqlDatabaseHelper

```
public class MySqlDatabaseHelper extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    Context ctx;
    String method,userID,userName,password,postData,result;

    MySqlDatabaseHelper(Context _ctx)
    {
        ctx = _ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            method = params[0].toString();

            if(method.equals("login"))
            {
                userName = params[1].toString();
                password = params[2].toString();
                URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/Android/login.php");

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoInput(true);

                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8");
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

                postData = URLEncoder.encode("uname","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(userName,"UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");

                bw.write(postData);

                bw.flush();
                bw.close();
                osw.close();
                os.close();

                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

                String line = "";
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    result += line;
                }

                br.close();
                isr.close();
                is.close();
                conn.disconnect();
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                return "NONE";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.d("Err",ex.getMessage());
            AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
            alert.setTitle("Something Went Wrong1");
            alert.setMessage("-"+ex.getMessage()+"-");
            alert.show();
            return "ERR";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
        alert.setTitle("Successfully Worked");
        alert.setMessage("-"+result+"-");
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting this error?

Comment: Can you tell me line of error

Comment: Actually I Am Getting Error In MainActivity Class ... see I Have Updated Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause:**

Because there might not be a message attached to the exception you are getting, it is possible to get this error in case of no message available to print. Better solution would be to use `ex.printStackTrace();` but you can fix this as below.

**Solution:**

Change

```
 Log.d("Err",ex.getMessage());
```

with

```
String err = (ex.getMessage() == null) ? "Error occured" : ex.getMessage();
Log.e("Err",err);
```

or

```
Log.e("Err", "" + ex.getMessage());
```

Comment: Actually I Am Having Error IN MainActivity Class Please Check it out and help me